# Error de Comandos en bot de musica para discord

Tags: python, discord.py

Hola estoy haciendo un bot de musica, y tengo un error que no me encuentra los comandos.
A mi parecer estan bien codeados e importados. Todavia no encuentro solucion, les dejo el codigo y el error a ver si me pueden ayudar. Pregunte en gitHub tambien y todavia no tengo la solucion. Entiendo esta bien la mayor parte de las cosas, no?

**main.py**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


#import all of the cogs
from music_cog import music_cog

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents = discord.Intents.all())

#remove the default help command so that we can write out own
bot.remove_command('help')

async def setup(bot): 
        await bot.add_cog(music_cog(bot))
#start the bot with our token
bot.run("TOKEN")
```

**music_cog.py**

```
from ast import alias
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

class music_cog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
        #all the music related stuff
        self.is_playing = False
        self.is_paused = False

        # 2d array containing [song, channel]
        self.music_queue = []
        self.YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist':'True'}
        self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}

        self.vc = None

     #searching the item on youtube
    def search_yt(self, item):
        with YoutubeDL(self.YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            try: 
                info = ydl.extract_info("ytsearch:%s" % item, download=False)['entries'][0]
            except Exception: 
                return False

        return {'source': info['formats'][0]['url'], 'title': info['title']}

    def play_next(self):
        if len(self.music_queue) > 0:
            self.is_playing = True

            #get the first url
            m_url = self.music_queue[0][0]['source']

            #remove the first element as you are currently playing it
            self.music_queue.pop(0)

            self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(m_url, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.play_next())
        else:
            self.is_playing = False

    # infinite loop checking 
    async def play_music(self, ctx):
        if len(self.music_queue) > 0:
            self.is_playing = True

            m_url = self.music_queue[0][0]['source']
            
            #try to connect to voice channel if you are not already connected
            if self.vc == None or not self.vc.is_connected():
                self.vc = await self.music_queue[0][1].connect()

                #in case we fail to connect
                if self.vc == None:
                    await ctx.send("Could not connect to the voice channel")
                    return
            else:
                await self.vc.move_to(self.music_queue[0][1])
            
            #remove the first element as you are currently playing it
            self.music_queue.pop(0)

            self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(m_url, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.play_next())
        else:
            self.is_playing = False


    @commands.command(name="play", aliases=["p","playing"], help="Plays a selected song from youtube")
    async def play(self, ctx, *args):
        query = " ".join(args)
        
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if voice_channel is None:
            #you need to be connected so that the bot knows where to go
            await ctx.send("Connect to a voice channel!")
        elif self.is_paused:
            self.vc.resume()
        else:
            song = self.search_yt(query)
            if type(song) == type(True):
                await ctx.send("Could not download the song. Incorrect format try another keyword. This could be due to playlist or a livestream format.")
            else:
                await ctx.send("Song added to the queue")
                self.music_queue.append([song, voice_channel])
                
                if self.is_playing == False:
                    await self.play_music(ctx)

    @commands.command(name="pause", help="Pauses the current song being played")
    async def pause(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.is_playing:
            self.is_playing = False
            self.is_paused = True
            self.vc.pause()
        elif self.is_paused:
            self.is_paused = False
            self.is_playing = True
            self.vc.resume()

    @commands.command(name = "resume", aliases=["r"], help="Resumes playing with the discord bot")
    async def resume(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.is_paused:
            self.is_paused = False
            self.is_playing = True
            self.vc.resume()

    @commands.command(name="skip", aliases=["s"], help="Skips the current song being played")
    async def skip(self, ctx):
        if self.vc != None and self.vc:
            self.vc.stop()
            #try to play next in the queue if it exists
            await self.play_music(ctx)


    @commands.command(name="queue", aliases=["q"], help="Displays the current songs in queue")
    async def queue(self, ctx):
        retval = ""
        for i in range(0, len(self.music_queue)):
            # display a max of 5 songs in the current queue
            if (i > 4): break
            retval += self.music_queue[i][0]['title'] + "\n"

        if retval != "":
            await ctx.send(retval)
        else:
            await ctx.send("No music in queue")

    @commands.command(name="clear", aliases=["c", "bin"], help="Stops the music and clears the queue")
    async def clear(self, ctx):
        if self.vc != None and self.is_playing:
            self.vc.stop()
        self.music_queue = []
        await ctx.send("Music queue cleared")

    @commands.command(name="leave", aliases=["disconnect", "l", "d"], help="Kick the bot from VC")
    async def dc(self, ctx):
        self.is_playing = False
        self.is_paused = False
        await self.vc.disconnect()
```

**ERROR**

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "help" is not found
```

No solo es el comando help, si no todos los que tengo.
¿Qué puedo hacer? Ya intente todo. Incluso en internet no logro encontrar la solucion. Pareciera que esta mal importado pero no es el caso.

Comment: El problema es que no estás llamando a la función setup en ningún lado. Por lo que el cog no se establece y los comandos no existen. Simplemente renombra tu función como "on_ready", quita el argumento bot y agrega el decorador bot.event. Con eso debería de ejecutarse cuando el bot está listo.

Comment: Buenisimo, pero qué función renombro y en qué archivo? Podrías guiarme? Muchas gracias

Comment: Perdon si no me aclaré bien. Sería la función setup en main.py

Comment: Gracias! ahi la actualice a lo siguiente: 

@bot.event
async def on_ready(): 
       await bot.add_cog(music_cog(bot))

# Pero sigue dando el mismo error :(

Comment: Que raro... Podrías probar a ponerle un print para comprobar si se ejecuta la función por favor?

Comment: Hola! Pude solucionarlo, cambie esa funcion como dijiste, pero tambien encontre un error en music_cog.py Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: De nada compa dolfi